# How do I do this query in MySQL? (datetime)

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

Suppose I have a datetime column in MySQL.
How do I select all that have a datetime within 2500 seconds of the current datetime?

```
SELECT ALL where current_datetime - that_datetime < 2500 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE that_datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 2500 SECOND
```

You want to do all the function calls and operation on constants as MySQL won't use indexes for fields used in any kind of expressions.

Comment: INTERVAL 2500 SECOND goes in the query too?

Comment: Yes, it is a way to do time arithmetic in MySQL. `SECOND` can be a `MINUTE`, `HOUR`, `DAY`, `MONTH`, `YEAR`, whatever you choose it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
SELECT * from table_name  
  where (extract ( epoch from current_datetime ) 
         - extract (epoch from that_datetime))  < 2500
```

Comment: That is a really bad way to do queries. Indexes goes out of the window.